# Imagick shows no supported formats when PHP is run from CLI, works when PHP is run from Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, imagemagick, imagick

I am using ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86 2016-03-27 and PHP Version 7.0.6 on a Windows system.

Everything works fine when I run PHP from a webpage through Apache, and if I call phpinfo() I will see a lot of supported formats in the Imagemagick module section.

However, if I run PHP from the CLI, phpinfo() will show no supported formats for Imagemagick. I suspect it's a problem with the location of the IM_MOD_* dll's. I've noticed that Apache pulls them from /bin, instead of from the Imagemagick installation folder. 
Maybe PHP-cli tries to pull them from somewhere else? But where? I've tried to copy the dlls to the following directories with no luck:

- C:\windows\system32
- Imagemagick root folder
- Imagemagick/modules/coders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I managed to solve my problem. The problem seems to be specific to Imagick. I have added an environmental variable named "MAGICK_HOME" that points to the ImageMagick folder (where all the dll's also reside) and now everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apache and the CLI use different .ini files which probably don't have the same configuration.

You can see the one being used in Apache in phpinfo() where the field "Loaded Configuration File" will display the file.

In the CLI if you run:

```
php --ini
```

you should see the one being used  in the console.

Verify that both files contain the configuration for Imagemagick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've run the test that you've proposed and both Apache and the CLI seem to use the same .ini: the standard one located in xampp/php/php.ini.

I've run phpinfo() in Apache and I get 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File C:\xampp\php\php.ini.

I get the exact same thing if I run a phpinfo() in the Console or if I use php.exe --ini

Any other ideas?